# Marshal.GetActiveObject throws error from C++/CLI but not C#

Tags: c#, com, c++-cli, rhapsody

I am trying to get access to an running instance of an application, Rational Rhapsody, through COM.  I am trying to use the C++/CLI COM calls.
From C++ calling:

```
rhapsody::RPApplication^ App = safe_cast<rhapsody::RPApplication^>( Marshal::GetActiveObject("Rhapsody.Application"));
```

Causes a COM Exception : 800401E3 (Operation Unavailable)

But, using `Marshal::GetActiveObject("Word.Application")` works just fine.  Using `gcnew rhapsody::RPApplication()` works fine to make a new instance and the same code in C#:

```
rhapsody.RPApplication App = (rhapsody.RPApplication) Marshal.GetActiveObject("Rhapsody.Application")
```

works just fine.
Any ideas why it doesn't work from C++/CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your main() routine in C++/CLI flagged with `[STAThread]`?  It's commonly required, especially when dealing with COM objects.

```
[STAThread]
int main(array<System::String^>^args)
{
     // code here...
}
```

Comment: I tried adding that, as another post here sugested it for the same error, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Ok, I tried it again just for fun and for some reason it works now.  Wierd.

Comment: Yay. I needed this to do: [Qt ComApp Example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/activeqt-comapp.html) with a C++/CLI wrapper instead of VB.NET.